# Start Activity in onReceive of a Boot Complete BroadcastReceiver in Android OS 9

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, bootcompleted

The activity won't start from a broadcast receiver of boot complete's onReceive even using Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK doesn't help and still through the same error.

Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
super.onReceive(context,intent);
if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) || 
  intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
  Intent mainActivityIntent = MainActivity.newIntent(context);
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  context.startActivity(mainActivityIntent);} 
}
```

Comment: I am trying this on Android 9 and still the same error, but this code works well on Android 7.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the flag for a different intent.
<s>intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);</s>

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
super.onReceive(context,intent);
if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) || 
  intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
  Intent mainActivityIntent = MainActivity.newIntent(context);
  // set flag on mainActivityIntent
  mainActivityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  context.startActivity(mainActivityIntent);} 
}
```